# Segmentation Fault using getcontext() in thread library

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to implement a user level thread library in C using systems calls such as get context, swap context , etc

I have a thread control block that looks like this :

```
struct tcb {
    int thread_id;
    int thread_pri;
    ucontext_t *thread_context;
    struct tcb *next;
}
```

And I have a function called init() that looks like this:

```
void t_init()
{
  tcb *tmp;
  tmp = malloc(sizeof(tcb));

  getcontext(tmp->thread_context);    /* let tmp be the context of main() */
 running_head = tmp;
}
```

I used gdb and I got a segmentation fault during runtime at the getcontext(tmp->thread_context) function.

I have read the man pages for getcontext() but am unsure as to why this is returning a segmentation fault to me!

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Check the pointer returned by `malloc`.

Comment: but i am getting an error at the getcontext() call. the man page for malloc suggests a void* if the sizeof is NULL, else a ptr that can be passed to free(). what am i doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't allocated any space for `thread_context`, try

```
void t_init()
{
    struct tcb *tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct tcb));
    if (!tmp)
        return -1;

    memset(&tmp, 0, sizeof(struct tcb));
    tmp->thread_context = malloc(sizeof(ucontext_t));
    if (!tmp->thread_context)
        return -1;

    getcontext(tmp->thread_context);
}
```

Comment: Note: for brevity there's no cleanup here, should at least `free(tmp)` if the thread_context allocation fails

Answer (score 0):

We can get the following information about [getcontext/setcontext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setcontext) ***"The GNU C Library Reference Manual Chapter:23 Non Locals Exits, Page 622)"***, and found the following

> While allocating the memory for the stack one has to be careful.
>   **Most modern processors keep track of whether a certain memory region is allowed to contain code which is executed or not. Data segments and
>   heap memory is normally not tagged to allow this. The result is that
>   programs would fail**. Examples for such code include the calling
>   sequences the GNU C compiler generates for calls to nested functions.
>   Safe ways to allocate stacks correctly include using memory on the
>   original threads stack or explicitly allocate memory tagged for
>   execution using memory mapped I/O.

This is causing the problem and you should use the recommended step to allocate the memory(using memory mapped I/O For more information, Please refer the libc manual).